# How to make a delete function on nested data in Laravel vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I always use this function format on deleting but seems not working on nested data.

```
        methods: {
            delete() {
                axios.delete('./../api/parent/' + this.parent.id)
                .then( response => {
                    if( response.status == 200 ) {
                    this.$emit('itemchanged');
                }
            })
            .catch ( error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
            }
        }

        in template I simply use this

        <v-btn icon @click="delete()"><v-icon>delete_forever</v-icon></v-btn>
```

but when dealing with data produced like this:

```
 return parents::with('children')->get();
```

I get this error:

```
    vue.common.dev.js?4650:630 [Vue warn]: Property or method "delete" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

what seems to be the problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this

```
 delete(item){
   this.parent.splice(this.parent.findIndex(e=> e.id == item.id),1)
 },


  <v-btn icon @click="delete(item)"><v-icon>delete_forever</v-icon></v-btn>
```

`v-data-table` has a different way of doing it. and I forgot mentioning about the `data table`